# Bash AWK find multiple patterns and assign to different variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, awk

I currently have a variable containing values resembling this:

```
x_snd_user=''
x_snd_appli=''
x_snd_text=''
x_rcv_user=''
x_rcv_appli=''
x_rcv_text=''
x_dup_from_xfer='0'
x_route_from_xfer='0'
x_route_to_xfer='0'
x_reply_by_xfer='0'
x_reply_to_xfer='0'
x_routed_to_XIB='N'
x_end_xfer_script=''
x_ftp_command=''
```

How can I, for example, match 3 patterns (`x_snd_appli, x_route_from_xfer, x_ftp_command`), format the patterns (`awk -F"'" '{print $2}'`) and assign them to different variables?

For example, I've got variables and want to assign the output to these:

```
 - Application= The value of <x_snd_appli>
 - Route= The value of <x_route_from_xfer>
 - Command= The value of <x_ftp_command>
```

Preferably not with something that needs to be installed as that's not possible.
So with AWK/perl if that's possible would be preferred.

The complete content of the variable is pretty big (about 45 lines) *and* it's possible that this runs about 1000x when I run the script 1x.
So I don't want to write data to a file/loop over it 10 times to awk/grep different values and assign them to variables.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: There you go, I've got 3 variables that I want to store the output in. (In reality I've got about 15 variables and the text file is way bigger so this is just a sample output.)

Comment: Can't you directly assign the variable names in script like: `Application="The value of $(grep -o "x_snd_appli" /path/file_name)"` and so on for other...?

Comment: As mentioned in my last line, the file is big and that would require to open the file about 15 times to process it so directly assigning it wouldn't be ideal for speed.

Comment: You could use `declare` like this `declare $(awk 'BEGIN{print "var1=x\nvar2=y"}')` then `echo $var1`and `echo $var2`. Substitute your own `awk` stuff, but you get the idea.

Comment: It is a very frequent antipattern to run a file through a shell loop and repeatedly extract individual fields with Awk, when the whole process would be elegant and trivial as a complete Awk script. Can you show us some things you want to do with these variables?

Comment: Or you could `read` multiple things `IFS='|' read v1 v2 v3 < <(awk 'BEGIN{print "a|b|c"}')`

Comment: @tripleee the reason I'm using bash is because I need bash for the previous iteration of the script (running a lot of system commands).
I would eventually like to line up all the values of these parameters so I have a nice output of application - user - command (as an example).

Comment: If you have confidence in the input, an Awk script which prints out the values as Bash assignments you can `eval` would work, but you obviously have to be careful.

Comment: When you say `I currently have a variable containing..` - do you **really** have a **variable** containing all of the text that follows or do you actually have a **file** containing multiple variable assignments as shown in that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have already is a valid shell script. You can just source it:

```
$ source ./file
$ echo $x_dup_from_xfer
0
```

To reassign, a little sed/awk can help, for example:

```
$ eval $(sed -n 's/^x_route_from_xfer=/Route=/p' file)
$ echo $Route
0
```

`-n` turns off automatic printing of lines and `s` substitutes, `p` prints the substitution result. Multiple sed commands:

```
$ eval $(sed -n 's/^x_route_from_xfer=/Route=/p;s/.../.../p' file)
```

Take care however, that source and eval require that it's you who controls the file contents.

The input may also come from a variable:

```
eval $(sed ... <<< "$var")
```

Comment: Good idea, however I can not apply this.
I guess I started this off wrong by saying I have an input file, those values are already in a variable and I read the variable and need to parse it.

Writing it to a file is not possible (too much data to constantly write/read).

Comment: @DaanTheunis It doesn't matter where the input is coming from. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

transfer="
x_snd_user=''
x_snd_appli=''
x_snd_text=''
x_rcv_user=''
x_rcv_appli=''
x_rcv_text=''
x_dup_from_xfer='0'
x_route_from_xfer='0'
x_route_to_xfer='0'
x_reply_by_xfer='0'
x_reply_to_xfer='0'
x_routed_to_XIB='N'
x_end_xfer_script=''
x_ftp_command=''
"
# or assign "transfer" with a output of other command.

while read -r line; do
    eval "$line"
done < <(
awk -F= 'BEGIN {
    a["x_snd_appli"] = "Application"
    a["x_route_from_xfer"] = "Route"
    a["x_ftp_command"] = "Command"
    }
    a[$1] {print a[$1] "=" $2}
' <<< "$transfer"
)

echo "Application=$Application"
echo "Route=$Route"
echo "Command=$Command"
```

We need to pay most attention when using `eval` as others mention.

Comment: This looked promising, however doesn't seem to work when using a variable as input? As the script does.. nothing, just stays black:

`transfer=\`output from application command\`
while read -r line; do
eval "$line"
done < <(
    awk -F= 'BEGIN {
    a["x_destination"] = "destination"
    }
    a[$1] {print a[$1] "=" $2}
    ' "$transfer"
    )

echo $destination`

Comment: I've modified the script for the case the input is supplied via a variable. Would you please test it?